# Primefaces datatable change paginationtemplate color

Tags: primefaces, datatable, pagination

Hi i am new to prime faces, what i am trying to achieve here is complete modification of the primefaces datatable.

Code:

```
<p:dataTable id="dataTable" var="c" value="#{databaseSearch.customerList}"  
                                 paginator="true" rows="10"
                                 paginatorTemplate="Page {CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}  Rows per page {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,30">
```

CSS Code:

```
#dataTable th {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;

}
#dataTable td {
    background: maroon;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: small;

}
```

I am able to change the color if the header and the rows but the options of paginatorTemplate such as {PageLinks} are still grey buttons 
[image: paginatorTemplate]

I want to change that grey color, Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try the following code:

```
    <style type="text/css">
      .ui-paginator-page{
        background-color:gray !important;   
      }
      .ui-paginator{ // for navigation bar
          background-color:gray !important;   
      }
    </style>
```

You can use `Inspect element` of browser to get component's css and element's css and then override them to get what you want.

Comment: Thanks ! but the .ui-paginator-page only changes the buttons Eg: 1, 2 .. the drop down and the page links remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's. It's works fine, but:
See:

```
.ui-paginator, th {
   background-color: white !important;
   background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: But see what? Is this an answer? What does it do?

Comment: Many primeface themes have background imganes. I just remembered about it. Sorry!